# Is it really impossible to surprise someone with a full-round action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, surprise

Is it true that not even the person/creature/thing doing the initial action that starts a combat is able to use a full-round action?

According to all sources I can find, the initial attack already is part of the surprise round, so you're only entitled to a move action or standard action; but that leads to an (in my opinion) absurd scenario, so I just wanted to be sure whether there is something I'm missing:

*Let's say sorcerer A is hiding in the bushes, 1HP left, waiting to finish sorcerer B (1HP left) off with magic missiles before B does the same to A. Then he suddenly spots sorcerer B - but sadly, he's some feet out of range. Now sorcerer A wants to use metamagic to double his magic missiles range and fire that on sorcerer B ... but now his magic missile takes a full-round action to cast, so sorcerer A cannot surprise sorcerer B with it anymore.*

Is this interpretation right RAW-wise or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that solely confirms your understanding? Or is there more to this question? That is, an answer can certainly just say *Yep* and provide a link to the surprise rules, but that seems like it would be… unsatisfactory? Unhelpful? For instance, it's possible a question like *How is game balance affected by a house rule saying that creatures can take a full-round action during the surprise round?* would yield more robust answers.

Comment: You're probably right; my phrasing is very narrow here. But as I already got a fully valid answer, I'll maybe ask a new question later about how to houserule the absurdity away without breaking the game.

Comment: Just so I can confirm the issue: What exactly is the absurdity? I mean, so that his spell can hit Sorcerer B from a greater distance, Sorcerer A has opted to change how he normally casts his spell so that it takes longer to cast—therefore sacrificing the advantage he'd normally enjoy—, and *Sorcerer A is aware of the potential consequences.* I guess I'd kind of like a definition of *absurd*: Is that chain of events unfair? Unrealistic? Some other adjective? (Honestly, I'm not trying to be a rules apologist here but understand the question!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. The best this sorcerer can do is [start a full-round action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#startCompleteFullRoundAction). At least, barring something like *time stop*.

Generally, the game is designed to avoid situations where someone doesn’t even get to roll.<sup>1</sup> In this situation, the game wants to give B a chance to roll initiative, so they have a chance to perhaps respond or escape.

Note that A could choose to sneak closer to B before initiating the attack, so that a standard action is sufficient. That gives B the chance to roll Spot and/or Listen, though. Still, you can do even better by hiding behind something—with total cover—so that you can 5-foot-step out as a free action and then shoot *magic missile* at B. That really gives B no opportunity to respond, but it requires a specific setup and great timing.

1. <sub>Though the game doesn't really do a good job of this, as the rest of the answer demonstrates ways around it. And at the high end of optimization, going first is almost always the same as winning a fight. And things like *nerveskitter* and *celerity* mean a spellcaster can go first every time, even when they shouldn’t.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

What the game does not specify is what happens if after a surprise round, you still have unaware combatants. For instance, in your example, what if *As* starting a full round action did not alert *B*? Ultimately, this is not covered in the rules, so it's up to the DM. The way I rule it is, **if at the end of a surprise round, you still have unaware combatants, another surprise round ensues**, but that's purely a house rule at this point.

I think KRyan's suggestion that sneaking closer wouldn't spoil the surprise supports this very idea - you would have to use a move action to sneak closer.